# Update JSON Data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on creating dynamic accordion by getting json data. I have implemented it and it works as expected, the code is as follows:

fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/68/](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/68/)

However, at this stage, I would like to edit accordion header (formationName) and once I click on the refresh button, it should update the json string. I couldn't figure out how to approach the problem.

```
   $("#refresh").click(function(){
    $( '.formationName' ).on( 'change', function(){
     var text=myData.offsetFormations[0].val();
     myData.offsetFormations[0]["formationName"]=text;
     json = JSON.stringify(jsonString);
     alert( jsonString );
    });
 });
```

By the way, I recently started on web development.

Answer (score 0):

You can detect changes to an input field when it's value changes with the jQuery `change` event.

```
$( '.myElement' ).change(function(){
    // Your Handler
} );
```

http://api.jquery.com/change/

After the field changes you can update the specified `formationName` with dot notation.

```
myObject[ 'key' ] = 'New Value';
```

Then you can use `JSON.stringify()` to rewrite the object as a JSON formatted String.

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ukgq2fsw/

Comment: Thanks Matt, My question is little more complicated. How do you capture when formationName change?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. You might possibly be able to use custom jQuery events. Are you changing the value in code, or is this a value that might change on it's own?

Comment: User could able to change formationName which is located in the accordion header. There are two steps I need help, how to capture this event and how to update json?

Comment: You can detect the change event with jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/change/) and then use `JSON.stringify();` to rewrite the object as a JSON String. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: it makes sense a lot. However, I have just followed your example, but no luck. Please see my updated question based on your approach.

Comment: In my example that I gave is to get first accordion header information and assign to value, and output  as an alertview

Comment: `myData.offsetFormations[0]` is javascript object (not a DOM element) and thus `val()` can't be applied to it (http://jsfiddle.net/j3dbowve/). You need to get the value of the text field `$( '.formationName' ).val()`. Lastly, you'll want to stringify `myData`, which is your JavaScript Object.

Comment: This also means, you'll need to switch those out for `<input>` instead of `<text>`

Comment: Modifying your code: http://jsfiddle.net/j3dbowve/10/ (sorry for the comments barage)