# Refresh Button Update Accordion in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to edit accordion header (formationName) and once I click on the refresh button, it should update the accordion header. I couldn't figure out how to approach the problem.

```
   $("#refresh").click(function(){
     myData.offsetFormations[0]["FormationName"]="party";
     json = JSON.stringify(myData);
     alert( json );
 });
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/76/

Comment: your refresh function is confusing. what is the point of the first two lines? I mean it looks like you are nesting the text. what does it have to do with the last two lines?

Comment: Didn't you already as this question earlier?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463789/update-json-data-in-javascript

Comment: Hello Jungy, I have sliglty changed the question and updated

Comment: ah...I think I was confused bc you updated your code...previously you stringified something else.

Comment: if you keep updating your code like that you're going to waste everyones time and make things really confusing.

Comment: Please check most clear version of my question. I would like to assign a string ("party") to my first header content. Once user clicks on refresh button, then AB would update with party

Comment: Sorry, Timmerz. I thought my question was not clear. Therefore, I wanted to illustrate it with a small example to make it much clear

Comment: I think part of the problem is you aren't even done working it out yourself. as jungy mentioned, you already posted this, and then you changed it slightly for this one, right? not only that, but you keep changing this one too. so the first step is just simplify.

Comment: @Timmerz, most of the comments, you're right. However, the question by itself it was quite complicated. Therefore, I only would like to know how to update header info by clicking refresh button with hardcoded string, party. By the way I am not expert on the web development. I have started 2-3 months ago.

Comment: @texas that code should update the myData formation name for the first item in the offsetFormations array.  I've tested it in your fiddle and it does work.

Comment: @jungy, yes it does update json object, but I would like to update accordion header as question title refers. That is different question from the one I asked before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your scenario. If there is a ton of data being refreshed often, you would want to do an in place edit.

If you just refresh when clicked and the data is insubstantial, just rebuild the table the way you originally did. An example of this (although it's not quite working):

http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/78/

```
var build = function(){
  //...build the grid/accordion here on demand (load,reload,programmatically)
};

var refresh = function(){
  //update json  
  build(); //rebuild;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
  // build on load
  build();
});
```

jQuery UI accordion needs to be destroyed on rebuild:

[re-initialize jquery accordion on callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301783/re-initialize-jquery-accordion-on-callback)

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/79/

You can also organize your code better and avoid global functions by following the module pattern:

```
var Grid = function(){
   var self = this;

   this.build = function(){
     ...
   };

   this.rebuild = function(){
      ...
   };

   this.init = function(){
     ...
     this.build();

     $('#refresh').on('click', this.refresh);

     ...etc
   };

   $(this.init);
};

var grid = new Grid();

grid.rebuild();
```

To answer your other question, just add an additional method:

```
this.setHeader = function(header){
   // similar to rebuild, change the json using param
   x[...] = header;
   this.build();
};
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. It updates the header but then accordion went wrong. I am also checking now

Comment: yes, I don't know what's up with that. seems it's a bug in the accordion. technically it should work. maybe it needs a destroy/cleanup function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301783/re-initialize-jquery-accordion-on-callback

Comment: Yeap. it is working. thanks a lot Timmerz. I have learned something totally new and interesting.

Comment: Sorry to bother Timmerz. What if a user wants to change accordion header (formationName) from accordion directly, rather than hard coded (party). By the way accordion header in editable. could you give me a hint to handle it?

Comment: yes, I updated my example to show how you can clean up your code. I will update the answer with an additional method that answers your last question.